# background-repeat round not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have difficulty getting `background-repeat:round;` to work in Chrome, although everywhere I look it up I read it is supported.

The URL is https://thecraftygardeners.co.uk/

I'm including a link to screenshots that show the difference between Chrome and Firefox views, including the inspector window to show the code. I'm using an up-to-date version of Chrome.

[firefox display top, Chrome display beneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv3vD.jpg)

Comment: There is not such thing as `background-repeat:round`. I would just suggest removing the css property all together. That should work. - https://caniuse.com/#search=background-repeat

Comment: @SidJoshi Yes there is, it's a part of CSS3.

Comment: There absolutely is such a thing as background-repeat: round, and caniuse suggests it's been in Chrome since version 32: https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-repeat-round-space however I've never implemented it, so not sure what the pitfalls/issues might be.

Comment: @SidJoshi you are incorrect....  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: `background-repeat: round` with one value effectively means `background-repeat: round round`. If you want to repeat only in the horizontal direction, it should be `round no-repeat`. But looking at your background images, i think a simple `background-size` and `transform` might be more suitable for your use. That 'round' repeat is meant for repeating patterns/textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble getting background-repeat:round to work in Chrome, although everywhere I look I'm told it is supported.

You have `background-position: center;` set for your buttons earlier. Try to overwrite it by adding `background-position: initial;` to your `.et_pb_button_[0|1|3]` and remove `background-size: contain;`. It seems to resolve the issue and the image will scale untill it fits 1 time as `round` option [suggests](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-repeat).

Answer (score -1):

try to use -webkit : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions

hope this helps.

-MultiDutch